# c++ does static allocation of string literals apply to any const char *

Tags: c++, string-literals

In Stroustrup C++ 4thEd p176, he states that this code is safe because string literals are allocated statically

```
const char∗ f() { return "some literal"; }
```

I have two questions about that :

First, at which revision of C++ did that became the case? ( and is it implementation dependent ? )

Second, does this extend to any "const char*" ? 
on this second part, I guess the answer is no, since this caused a run time error:

```
const char* make_const_char_ptr(){ 
    const char res [] = {'a','b','c', '\0' }; 
    return res; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, at which revision of C++ did that became the case?

Always been the case since C++ was standardised. String literals have static [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

> Second, does this extend to any "const char*" ?

Yes, if you the the returned object has static storage. But that's not the case in your example. `res` has automatic storage duration. Instead you can do:

```
const char* make_const_char_ptr() { 
    static const char res [] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }; 
    return res; 
}
```

and it's valid.

Comment: "Always been the case since C++ was standardised." and also long before that. <g>

Answer (score 0):

To return a reference or a pointer to a variable with the automatic storage duration from a function invokes undefined behavior because after exiting the function the referenced or pointed variable will not be alive.

String literals have static storage duration so you may return a pointer or a reference to a string literal.

Also you can return a reference or a pointer to a function local variable that is declared with the storage specifier static.

For example using this function definition

```
const char* make_const_char_ptr(){ 
    const char res [] = {'a','b','c', '\0' }; 
    return res; 
}
```

this code snippet

```
const char *s = make_const_char_ptr();
size_t n = strlen( s );
```

invokes undefined behavior because the pointed string stored in the array `res` with the automatic storage duration will not be alive.

However if the function will be defined the following way

```
const char* make_const_char_ptr(){ 
    const static char res [] = {'a','b','c', '\0' }; 
    return res; 
}
```

then this code snippet

```
const char *s = make_const_char_ptr();
size_t n = strlen( s );
```

is correct because the array res is still alive. The qualifier const does not matter in this case. That is it does not influence on the life time of the array.

Pay attention to that it is unimportant how the array is initialized: whether using a string literal or  an initializer list of characters.

This declaration within the function

```
const char res [] = { "abc" };
```

has automatic storage duration if the storage specifier static is not present.

And below there is a demonstrative program where a string literal is returned from a function by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

decltype( auto ) f()
{
    return ( "hello World" );
}

void g( const char *s )
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    decltype( auto ) s = f();

    g( s );

    std::cout << std::extent<std::remove_reference<decltype( s )>::type>::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hello World
12
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement refers to literals NOT to any const char*, you've got to mind the difference between a const char* and a literals. 
The first line of code you mentioned:

```
const char∗ f() { return "some literal"; }
```

contains a literal "some literal" the compiler interpret that by statically allocating that string represented. 
The other piece of code:

```
const char* make_const_char_ptr(){ 
    const static char res [] = {'a','b','c', '\0' }; 
    return res; 
}
```

is interpreted as to allocate an array of char and then return the pointer to the begin of that array, but as soon the program returns from the function the array is being deallocated (so it is not safe to access any more to the address pointed by the returning value. Type of return is the same for both function but in first case is linked to a literal (statically allocated, not destroyed on return) in the other case you tell compiler to allocate an array which scope is confined to the function itself (contrary to the static case of the literal).